# Find frequencies of combinations where the data.frame needs to be parsed

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency, heatmap

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, but I can't figure it out!! Suppose I have a dataframe that has the following information:

```
aaa<-c("A,B","B,C","B,D,E")
vvv<-c("101","101,102","102,103,104")
data_h<-data.frame(aaa,vvv)
data_h
    aaa         vvv
1   A,B         101
2   B,C     101,102
3 B,D,E 102,103,104
```

Desired output is a frequency map of individual hits, for subsequent analysis in a heat map. So:

```
  101   102   103   104
A  1     0     0     0
B  2     2     1     1
C  1     1     0     0
D  0     1     1     1
E  0     1     1     1
```

How do I make this transformation? I've seen many similar examples, but none where the contents of the data-frame need to be parsed.

The goal is to ultimately use heatmap or something similar on the output table to visualize the correlation between "aaa" and "vvv".

Comment: I have a question? in first row only 101 is there still it was mapped with B, but next two rows have specifically mapped with aaa and vvv... How to go about this...

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand... what's the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a base R solution in 4 lines of code.  First we define a function, `spl` which splits the components of a comma separated string producing a vector of all the fields.   `eg` takes two string arguments and applies `spl` to each of them and then creates a grid of the result of the splitting.  Finally we apply `eg` to each row of `data_h`, `rbind` the results together and tabulate them with `xtabs`:

```
spl <- function(x) strsplit(as.character(x), ",")[[1]]
eg <- function(aaa, vvv) expand.grid(aaa = spl(aaa), vvv = spl(vvv))
dd <- do.call("rbind", Map(eg, data_h$aaa, data_h$vvv))
xtabs(data = dd)
```

The result is:

```
   vvv
aaa 101 102 103 104
  A   1   0   0   0
  B   2   2   1   1
  C   1   1   0   0
  D   0   1   1   1
  E   0   1   1   1
```

**dcast** Alternately replace the last line of code above (the one with the `xtabs`) with:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(dd, aaa ~ vvv, fun = length, value.var = "vvv")
```

in which case the result is:

```
  aaa 101 102 103 104
1   A   1   0   0   0
2   B   2   2   1   1
3   C   1   1   0   0
4   D   0   1   1   1
5   E   0   1   1   1
```

**tapply**. Another alternative would be `tapply` (however, it will fill in empty cells with NA rather than 0):

```
tapply(1:nrow(dd), dd, length)
```

**ADDED** Alternatives.  Some improvements.

Comment: This near about kills my computer processing, but works also! Unfortunately, gives a different answer than splitstackshape solution above... trying the edit.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "unfortunately". This gives the answer asked for in the question.

Comment: @AmitKohli, I also don't understand your use of "unfortunately" in your comment.

Comment: Have added an alternative to xtabs in case its faster.

Comment: The 'unfortunately' means that I have to check manually with the real data to find if it's accurate. But since I can't reproduce the edit in the splitstackshape, I'm marking this as THE answer. Thanks!

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, It's not recognizing the "f" in your `dcast` solution above... but the xtabs one works. Now if I can only get rid of the zeros in the matrix I'll be golden!

Comment: If getting rid of zeros means replacing them with `NA` then add the `fill = NA_integer_` argument to the `dcast` statement.

Comment: `xtabs` and `dcast` seem to be about the same, for at least up to 10K rows (which is where I stopped testing). Perhaps `dcast.data.table` would be a better option for larger datasets.

Answer (score 4):

The shape of the data.frame suggests using `splitstackshape` package. But I don't know very well this package so I just use it to reshape the data, and then compute frequencies by hand using `table`:

```
library(splitstackshape)
data_h_split <- concat.split.multiple(data_h,1:2)

# aaa_1 aaa_2 aaa_3 vvv_1 vvv_2 vvv_3
# 1     A     B  <NA>   101    NA    NA
# 2     B     C  <NA>   101   102    NA
# 3     B     D     E   102   103   104
```

Once you have the data in this format (no comma , regular columns), it is easy to compute frequencies using `table`( you can use `tapply`,`reshape`):

```
table(cbind.data.frame(ff= unlist(data_h_split[1:3]),
                       xx= unlist(data_h_split[4:6])))
   xx
ff  101 102 103 104
  A   1   0   0   0
  B   1   1   0   0
  C   0   1   0   0
  D   0   0   1   0
      0   0   0   0
  E   0   0   0   1
```

---

#### Ananda's edit

Here's a multi-step approach to get the result using "splitstackshape" to work for this.

```
library(splitstackshape)

## Split the "vvv" column first, and reshape at the same time
x <- concat.split.multiple(data_h, split.cols="vvv", ",", "long")

## Add an ID column
x$id <- 1:nrow(x)

## Split the "aaa" column next, again reshaping as we do so
x <- concat.split.multiple(x[complete.cases(x), ], split.cols="aaa", ",", "long")

## Use `table` with `droplevels`
with(droplevels(x), table(aaa, vvv))
#    vvv
# aaa 101 102 103 104
#   A   1   0   0   0
#   B   2   2   1   1
#   C   1   1   0   0
#   D   0   1   1   1
#   E   0   1   1   1
```

Comment: This definitely works... I'm holding off on marking as solved because it's not very extrapolatable because in my application, I needed to find out that the columns were [1:208] and [209:416]... but thanks and good job!

Comment: @AmitKohli, if the columns are named similarly, can't you just use `grep` with the column names?

Comment: @AnandaMahto thanks for the edit. I don't mind any edit :) you are always welcome.

Comment: Can't reproduce your edit Ananda... it freezes my computer when I try it with my real data (but my computer isn't great... so it's probably not your code). Regarding your comment, what would you like me to grep?

Comment: @AmitKohli, Check out the results I've posted at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24146951/1270695

Answer (score 3):

My `concat.split.multiple` function is in great need of a rewrite to improve its efficiency. I've done some work on that in my [**`cSplit`** function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733), which might be useful if you have a particularly large dataset.

Here's how I would solve your given problem with `cSplit`:

```
table(
  cSplit(
    cSplit(data_h, splitCols = 2, sep = ",", 
           direction = "long", makeEqual = FALSE), 
    splitCols = 1, sep = ",", direction = "long", 
    makeEqual = FALSE))
#    vvv
# aaa 101 102 103 104
#   A   1   0   0   0
#   B   2   2   1   1
#   C   1   1   0   0
#   D   0   1   1   1
#   E   0   1   1   1
```

It seems to be pretty efficient too...

First, the functions to test:

```
fun1 <- function() table(cSplit(cSplit(df, 2, ",", "long", FALSE), 1, ",", "long", FALSE))

fun2 <- function() {
  spl <- function(x) strsplit(as.character(x), ",")[[1]]
  eg <- function(aaa, vvv) expand.grid(aaa = spl(aaa), vvv = spl(vvv))
  dd <- do.call("rbind", Map(eg, df$A, df$V))
  xtabs(data = dd)
}
```

Second, some sample data. Change `Nrows` and re-generate to see the effect on different sized `data.frame`s.

```
set.seed(1)
Nrow <- 100
aaa <- 100:200
vvv <- LETTERS
maxA <- 10
maxV <- 10
Aaa <- sample(maxA, Nrow, TRUE)
Vvv <- sample(maxV, Nrow, TRUE)
A <- vapply(seq_along(Aaa), function(x) 
  paste(sample(aaa, Aaa[x], TRUE), collapse = ","), character(1L))
V <- vapply(seq_along(Vvv), function(x) 
  paste(sample(vvv, Vvv[x], TRUE), collapse = ","), character(1L))
df <- data.frame(A, V)
head(df)
#                                         A                   V
# 1                             127,122,152       E,E,O,S,W,S,M
# 2                         127,118,152,156             V,A,Z,Q
# 3                 113,125,172,197,110,177               L,A,T
# 4 195,182,131,165,196,196,134,126,116,132 F,Z,X,S,T,M,W,E,Q,H
# 5                             151,193,151       L,B,E,B,Y,I,N
# 6     126,104,142,186,135,113,137,163,139               Q,G,N
```

Compare the two approaches to make sure the results are the same:

```
X <- fun1()
Y <- fun2()
all(X == Y[dimnames(X)[[1]], dimnames(X)[[2]]])
# [1] TRUE
```

Benchmark (on 100 rows).

```
library(microbenchmark)
## Nrow = 100
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
#  fun1()  7.263802  7.326237  7.440843  7.868905 10.26451    10
#  fun2() 62.869130 64.046836 68.525880 73.595061 80.02027    10
```

Benchmark (on 1000 rows).

```
## Nrow = 1000
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#  fun1()  19.2303  20.21857  23.14337  26.97776  35.56338    10
#  fun2() 775.6586 815.01639 835.98951 852.47804 888.15345    10
```